# Return information from a Date Range with two criteria

Tags: sql, t-sql, between, date-range, datepart

I'm new to SQL and I'm trying to extract data from a certain date range. In my case, I want data just from a week ago. I'm trying to get clients who turned 13 last week but my between clause isn't working. Any suggestions?

```
select distinct [Account Number], [Date of Birth], [Age in Years]
from adhoc.[Patient Demographics] 
where [Age in Years] = 13 and between datepart(dd,getdate()) and datepart(dd,getdate()-7)
```

Columns are:

```
PracName (varchar(95), null)
Patient ID(int, not null)
Account number (varchar(15), null)
Title (varchar(50), null
First Name (Varchar(95), not null)
Middle Name (varchar(95), not null)
Last Name (varchare(95), not null)
Gender (varchar(1), null
Date of Birth(datetime, null)
Age in Years(int, null)
Age in Months (int, null)
Age in Weeks (int, null)
Age in Days (int, null)
Age in UDS (int, null)
Age Group (varchare(7), no null)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please provide the column field. I believe you need to use **OR** instead of **AND**

```
select distinct [Account Number], [Date of Birth], [Age in Years]
from adhoc.[Patient Demographics] 
where [Age in Years] = 13 OR[Age in Years] between datepart(dd,getdate()) and datepart(dd,getdate()-7)
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this:

```
select distinct [Account Number], [Date of Birth], [Age in Years]
from adhoc.[Patient Demographics] 
where [Age in Years] = 13 and DATEADD(YEAR, 13, [Date of Birth]) between DATEADD(DAY, -7, GETUTCDATE()) AND getdate()
```

I am first adding 13 years to the current `Date of Birth` and than checking if the result date is in the past 7 days from now.